# Application has not been registered

Tags: android, google-chrome, reactjs, debugging, native

I know theres a few posts on this site regarding this error message but my issue doesn't seem to be answered by any of the solutions.

I am debugging my React Native app using my Android testing phone. Everything works correctly until I start using "Debug JS Remotely" with Chrome's React Native Debugger. That is when Chrome gives me this error. I do not have any other packages running and my AppRegistry has the correct name.

Edit: I restarted my computer and I managed to get Chrome React Native Debugger working without this error. However, upon reloading the app this error starts to pop up again.

Edit: Another thing to note, my application is working correctly when I'm not using Chrome's debugger. I have live reloading on and my app updates upon making changes to my files. This issue only appears when I turn on Remote JS Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

in two situations this will happen:
1: when your development server is not up so try this:
react-native start
2: otherwise try this in terminal react-native run-android

Comment: I have the react-native/npm package window open. This problem occurs while my development server is running. I have my android phone connected through wifi so run-android will say no devices connected.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that the packager is running from same directory as the app.
2. Make sure that the string in *MainActivity.java* matches the string in *index.android.js*.